# mongodb connection error: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ecs

I am using `mongoose` to connect to a remote mongodb server as below; when running on my local machine it works fine; I can also shell into the db without any problem locally. But after I deployed my express api to a server running on a container in AWS ECS. I got: `Server selection timed out after 30000 ms`

`process.env.MOCK_DB=mongodb://username:password@somedomain.com:37017/db_name?directConnection=true`

```
  connect(process.env.MOCK_DB, { autoIndex: false }, (err: any) => {
    if (err) {
      log('cannot connect to mongodb:', err.message);
    } else {
      isDBConnected = true;
      log("Connected to mongodb!");
    }
  });
```

What do I need to config?

Comment: Is the ECS container running in a public subnet, or a private subnet? Does it have a public IP assigned to it? Is this task deploying to EC2 or Fargate?

Comment: server selection timeout just says that your operation can't select a server to be launched on. The reason why it can't do it is mentioned in servers description that you didn't provide. Also, you use `directConnection=true` that means that you're connecting to a particular node directly, so make sure that this node is available

Answer (score -2):

Please try connecting with time limit more than 30s.
Like this:

```
process.env.MOCK_DB=mongodb://username:password@somedomain.com:37017/db_name?directConnection=true&socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000
```

You can visit this [link](https://bobcares.com/blog/mongodb-connection-timeout/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20MongoDB%20connection%20timeout,1%20second%20to%2030%20seconds.) and find the appropriate solution for your error.

Comment: don't think that's the problem